# how to set Evolution for pop3?

Tags: 12.04, evolution

I begin using Evolution 3.2.3 with Ubuntu 12.04 instead of Microsoft Outlook 2003 with Windows XP. I have set Evolution mail account parameters according to the Outlook settings. When clicking at 'Send/Receive' button above, I only get a message

> 'Error while Fetching Mail.*Unable to connect to POP server pop3.seznam.cz: No support for requested authentication mechanism.*'

I have tried changing Security from SSL to 'No encryption', but it has not helped. The 'Authentication Type' is 'Password', the field besides it is not accessible and shows 'Check for Supported Types'.

Answer (score 1):

Experiments and information from post server providers result in:

- Port 995,
- SSL encryption,
- Authentication Type: Password.

It works OK for both pop3 servers I use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `login` for pop3 server access. Evolution will ask for pass on first send/recv.

Comment: I have not found how to `login` to the _pop3.seznam.cz_ via Evolution. I have tried to write it in the address line of my Google Chrome Internet Browser, but no password was required.

Comment: change The 'Authentication Type' from 'Password' to `Login`

Comment: The 'Authentication Type' was originally 'Login' and the same error message appeared. Now the 'Login' was shown by a strikethrough font. Nevertheless I have set it to 'Login', the font changed to normal, but the same error message appears yet. Originally the Evolution asked for the password, but I have set that it should be remembered; now no password is required.

Comment: Port must be 110. Telnet from my pc to server work on port 110

Comment: POP port is 110.

Comment: Any differences from outlook settings?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14092/discussion-between-tomas-peceny-and-2707974)